# How to upsert in Postgres on conflict on one of 2 columns?

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

Is it possible to do `upsert` in Postgres 9.5 when conflict happens on one of 2 columns in a table.? Basically I have 2 columns and if either column throws unique constraint violation, then I would like to perform update operation.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, and this behaviour is default. Any unique constraint violation constitutes a conflict and then the `UPDATE` is performed if `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` is specified. The `INSERT` statement can have only a single `ON CONFLICT` clause, but the `conflict_target` of that clause can specify multiple column names each of which must have an index, such as a `UNIQUE` constraint. You are, however, limited to a single `conflict_action` and you will not have information on which constraint caused the conflict when processing that action. If you need that kind of information, or specific action depending on the constraint violation, you should write a trigger function but then you lose the all-important atomicity of the `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO ...` statement.

Comment: I'm not sure this is 100% correct, admittedly the question is vague. If the 2 columns have different unique constraints (what I understood from the question), then the ON CONFLICT can only be used for DO NOTHING. You can't seem to chain or "disjunction" the so-called conflict_target.

Comment: @Jeff Expanded my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your update. It answers my own question about what whether or not we can handle two different violations with the same INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

I think in Postgres 9.5 ON CONFLICT can have only one constraint or multiple column names but on that multiple columns must have combine one index