# Postgres conflict handling with multiple unique constraints

Tags: postgresql

I would like to use the insert.. on confict do update.. syntax with a table that has unique constraints on two columns. Is this possible?

e.g. mytable has separate unique constraints on col1 and col2.

I can write:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(col1, col2, col3) values ('A', 'B', 0) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

However this doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('A', 'B', 0) 
ON CONFLICT 
DO UPDATE SET col3 = EXCLUDED.col3 + 1;
```

ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name

This also doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('A', 'B', 0)
ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) 
DO UPDATE SET col3 = EXCLUDED.col3 + 1;
```

ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

This syntax seems to be designed for a single composite unique constraint over two columns, rather than two constraints.

Is there any way to do a conditional update if either unique constraint is violated? This question [How to upsert in Postgres on conflict on one of 2 columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031934/how-to-upsert-in-postgres-on-conflict-on-one-of-2-columns) alludes to it but doesn't provide the syntax.

Comment: IMHO the question makes no sense. In the `simple case on conflict`: the key is kept, and (some of) the dependent fields are updated. In your case, you intend to update another (candidate) key. In fact, you attempt to update both (candidate) keys, which is beyond my logic.

Comment: I've updated the example to be more realistic. The idea is to keep a counter column up to date which matches on either unique column, or insert zero if neither exists.

Comment: Adding an extra constraint `UNIQUE (col1, col2)` will probably do what you want. (it is logically redundant, but the data model makes little or no sense anyway)

Answer (score 63):

The `ON CONFLICT` clause needs a single unique constraint when we ask it to `DO UPDATE`. When a primary key is defined, it is sufficient to just reference the column name; which is the dominant example one tends to find.

You mention that you have 'separate unique constraints on col1 and col2', so I might assume your table definition is similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(       
    col1 varchar UNIQUE,    
    col2 varchar UNIQUE,    
    col3 int
);
```

But your query is referencing a composite constraint; rather than separate constraints. A modified table definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable2(  
    col1 varchar UNIQUE,
    col2 varchar UNIQUE,
    col3 int,
    CONSTRAINT ux_col1_col2 UNIQUE (col1,col2)
);
```

would work with your query above:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('A', 'B', 0)
ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) 
DO UPDATE SET col3 = EXCLUDED.col3 + 1;
```

You can reference this unique constraint as either `ON CONFLICT (col1, col2)` or as `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT ux_col1_col2`.

**But wait, there's more...**

> The idea is to keep a counter column up to date which matches on
>   either unique column, or insert zero if neither exists...

That's a different path than you're taking here. "*matches on either unique column*" allows for matching on both, either, or neither. If I understand your intent, just have a single label and increment the counters on the applicable records. So:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable2(  
    col1 varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    col3 int
);
INSERT INTO mytable2(col1,col3)
SELECT incr_label,0
FROM (VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C')) as increment_list(incr_label)
ON CONFLICT (col1)
DO UPDATE SET col3 = mytable2.col3 + 1
RETURNING col1,col3;
```

Answer (score 9):

Because the *conflict_target* can't be two different unique constraints you have to use a simulated upsert and handle the conflicts yourself.

> -- Desired
>
> INSERT INTO mytable(col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('A', 'B', 0)
> ON CONFLICT
> DO UPDATE SET col3 = EXCLUDED.col3 + 1;

```
WITH upsert AS (
  UPDATE mytable
  SET col1 = 'A', col2 = 'B', col3 = col3 + 1
  WHERE col1 = 'A' OR col2 = 'B'
  RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 'A', 'B', 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert);
```

This statement will result in rows that contain A or B or both, in other words uniqueness on `col1` and uniqueness on `col2` is satisfied.

Unfortunately this solution suffers from the limitation that there must be some logical link between A and B, otherwise if `('A', null)` is inserted, followed by `(null, B)` and then by `(A, B)` you will end up with two rows, both incremented by the third insert:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    A | null |    1 |
| null |    B |    1 |
```

Comment: Is there any way to use `RETURNING` with this combination of queries? The second query wouldn't return a value if it the upsert branch was followed. Would a 3rd `SELECT` query be needed?

Answer (score 2):

(copied from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76364001/543875) in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35888012/543875))

It seems to be the case that for the OP `col1` and `col2` are independently unique. So that a combined unique constrained will NOT solve the insert/on conflict problem, as suggested in other answers.

One solution to this is a CTE which firstly only inserts a new row with `col1` set and assigns a random value for `col2` (avoiding a constraint violation on `col2`). And only then it updates `col2` to its final value. Now this is what happens:

1. If `col1` is duplicated, the first clause's conflict will hit and not insert a new row. Otherwise a new row is inserted with `col1` set to its final value and `col2` set to a temporary and unique value.
2. If `col2` is duplicated, the second clause's conflict will hit and simply store the final value of `:col2`. Either for the existing row or for the newly created row from the insert clause.

Given that `col1` and `col2` are both strings/texts, we can use `gen_random_uuid()::text` to generate a unique string for the first insert clause:

```
with
    row as (
        insert into table(col1, col2)
        values(:col1, gen_random_uuid()::text)
        on conflict(col1) do set col1 = :col1
        returning col1
    )
update table
set col2 = :col2
from row
where row.col1 = :col1
returning col1, col2
```

with `:col1` and `:col2` being variables passed to the query.

Now if your column isn't a string/text you can come up with other unique values such as temporarily assigning `-1` to `col2`, knowing that all your values are otherwise positive.

For when you have more than 2 independently unique columns, above approach scales in so far as you can move more (and even all) column updates into the CTE clause:

```
with
    row as (
        insert into table(col1, col2, ..., colN)
        values(
            :col1,
            gen_random_uuid()::text,
            ...
            gen_random_uuid()::text,
        )
        on conflict(col1) do set col1 = :col1
        returning col1
    ),
    col2_update as (
        update table
        set col2 = :col2
        from row
        where row.col1 = :col1
    ),
    ...
    colN_update as (
        update table
        set colN = :colN
        from row
        where row.col1 = :col1
    )
select col1, col2, ..., colN from row
```