# Two conflict targets for ON CONFLICT upsert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to unique constraint set in my table structure. One of them is a set of `(store_id, cart_id, product_id)` and the other one is `(warehouse_id, cart_id, product_id)`

I'm trying to upsert products using ON CONFLICT clause in SQL like below.

```
    insert into "public"."cart_items" ("cart_id", "product_id", "quantity", "unit_sell_price", "warehouse_id") values (7, 19340, 41, 184.25145454, 1)
 ON CONFLICT (store_id, cart_id, product_id)
                  DO UPDATE SET
                  discount = EXCLUDED.discount,
                  coupon_id = EXCLUDED.coupon_id,
                  unit_sell_price = EXCLUDED.unit_sell_price,
                  quantity = EXCLUDED.quantity,
                  meta = EXCLUDED.meta,
                  cart_id = EXCLUDED.cart_id
                RETURNING *;
```

I know how to handle it for a single constraint like above, but how can I check for both constraint sets? like `ON CONFLICT (store_id, cart_id, product_id) OR (warehouse, cart_id, product_id)`

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: If those are the only unique or primary key constraints on the table, you could use `ON CONFLICT` without any constraint specification. Then any constraint violations are handled.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36886134/297331